# Using Azure AD B2C in a Xamarin Forms Mobile Apps application causes constant redirection to the login page

Tags: azure, authentication, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

I have an Azure Mobile App that I want to protect with Azure AD B2C. I have been following https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-mobile-app/ and implemented the Client-Managed Authentication. The token from the B2C tenant seems ok. And the async login to the MobileServicesClient returns the same user.

However, when I try to access a function that is decorated with [Authorize], I get redirected to `/.auth/login/aad?ReturnUrl={requested url}`.

Here is a sample of the logs (https removed as stackoverflow does not allow me to post so many links):

```
Received request: GET ://xxx.azurewebsites.net/tables/table1?$filter=(Email%20eq%20'x%40x.x')
JWT validation succeeded. Subject: 'sid:x', Issuer: '://xxx.azurewebsites.net/'.

Authenticated sid:x successfully using 'Session Token' authentication.

Received request: GET ://xxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad?ReturnUrl=%2ftables%2ftable1

Information Redirecting: ://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fxxx.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=x&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&p=b2c_1_susi&nonce=x&state=redir%3D
```

The result is that I get JSON parsing errors in my Xamarin Forms app because the calls are not returning JSON but whole web pages.

My mobile services app (`xxx.azurewebsites.net`) uses Active Directory Authentication, uses the application ID of the B2C tenant in the advanced configuration, the issuer url is the metadata endpoint of the sign in-sign up policy and the token audience is `://xxx.azurewebsites.net` or `://xxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback` (the result is the same).

In the B2C tenant (`xxx.onmicrosoft.com`) I have a web app and a native app. The web app has as reply url `://xxx.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback` and the native app goes to `msal{application id}://auth` or `msal{application id}://easyauth.callback` (again the result is the same).

Can someone explain why the redirect occurs and how to prevent it?